# Send keystrokes to two windows at once

Tags: linux, bash, script

What I want to do:  Be able to enter keystrokes while one program is in focus, but also send the same keystrokes to a second program on the other screen.

What I have tried: xvkbd - I've tried multiples ways of using this, and none seem to work properly for what I need.
What I have looked into but cant do: keyboardcast - I can't for the life of me find the source files and there's only deb files everywhere for it, no RPM. (I run Fedora 21)

Actual application: What I intend to use this for, if for entering my password in multiple EvE-Online clients at once, to make logging into my accounts alittle more streamlined.
I already have a script that allows me to start them all at once, on the proper monitors (using wmctrl) but I still have to enter passwords one at a time.  Since I use the same password for all 3, it's abit easier to just clone keystrokes, if possible.

I have had some success with writing in xvkbd -window $WID -text "REDACTED\r" at the end of the script that starts the program and uses wmctrl to set their location (the windowid for WID is retrieved through wmctrl).

If I use this script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 WINEDEBUG=-all wine64 "/home/REDACTED/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/CCP/EVE/bin/exefile.exe" &
 PID=$!
 while [ "$WID" == "" ]; do
  WID=$(wmctrl -lp | grep $PID | cut "-d " -f1)
 done
 wmctrl -i -r $WID -e 0,0,1680,1050 &&
 sleep 2
 xvkbd -window $WID -text "REDACTED"\r"
```

I can successfully automate the login process. Simply running the script will open the game client, move it to whichever monitor I tell it and resize it to what I tell it, it then waits 2 seconds and then pipes my password through xvkbd and logs me in.

I have also had success in making the script open a box for me to type my password in, so that my PW isn't saved in a file somewhere.

However, when I try to do this with TWO clients, NEITHER of them gets the text. If I offset the wait time of the two, between when the window is made and the xvkbd is used, only the one with the longer wait time recieves the information.

I am under the impression it might have something to do with window focus, but making wmctrl set focus to each window (wmctrl -a $WID) then having xvkbd go through, doesn't seem to work, if I don't offset the sleep timers neither program gets it, if I do, only the one with a longer timer does.  I've tried offsetting them by as little at 1sec and as much as 10sec and it's the same.

Is there any other way to do this? if so how? Am I missing something in my script somewhere? or is this simply not possible?  Thanks.

Comment: `tmux` with `set synchronize-panes` toggled on.

Comment: How exactly would this be done?  I don't know much about tmux but i though tit's funtionality was most limited to terminal multiplexing.

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't realize these were GUIs

Answer (score 0):

Source can be found [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/keyboardcast/keyboardcast_0.1.1.orig.tar.gz).

Extract the package in `/usr/local/src`:

```
tar -xvf keyboardcast_0.1.1.orig.tar.gz
cd keyboardcast-0.1.1/
make
su -
make install
```

Executable will be placed in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: For those ok with Alt-Tab like behavior and a small delay in between entering into separate windows, you can use `xdotool`, [as outlined here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302626/is-there-a-way-to-send-the-switch-windows-signal-without-alt-tab). I use this approach emulate a presenter console on dual monitors (browser window with slides + pdf with notes).